# Can you reopen the question "What war crimes has Ukraine committed during the 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine?"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen

Part1. [Can you reopen the question "What war crimes has Ukraine committed during the 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine?"](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/can-you-reopen-the-question-what-war-crimes-has-ukraine-committed-during-the-20)

Part2. [Question was reopened and then edited to be shorter and then closed again?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6309/question-was-reopened-and-then-edited-to-be-shorter-and-then-closed-again)

---

Ok I removed the thing people made a big deal of. In my opinion there's nothing wrong with what I asked. It's like if there were some article or some passage in a textbook.

1. What do I misunderstand? Am I forbidden to ask about passages in a textbook?
2. Ok anyhoo now reopen please?

[What type and scale of war crimes has Ukraine committed during the 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/73883/what-war-crimes-has-ukraine-committed-during-the-2022-russian-invasion-of-ukrain)

Answer (score 3):

I voted to close because it was not so much asking about the possibility of war crimes by Ukraine as it was meandering on about the formatting and content of a wikipedia article.

Mine wasn't the only such comment:

- *Question 1: We didn't write that article. If you don't like the way it flows, you need to discuss that with the Wikipedia editors who wrote it. –*
- *I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be about problems with a wiki article as well as ongoing events that we don't have all the needed information for to determine an answer.*
- *Every Wikipedia article has a Talk page, and this article was very active. You can discuss the article on that page instead.*

These are upvoted.  3, 5, 3 votes, respectively.

You then claim to have fixed this but your question is still heavily based on wikipedia:

> **It's kind of irritating, but unless I'm missing something in the 3 paragraphs before the table of contents in the Wikipedia page War crimes** in the 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine, there doesn't seem to be quite a distinction like
>
> War crimes of Russia: So and so
>
> War crimes of Ukraine: So and so
>
> **Not sure how those 3 paragraphs arrange stuff, but anyway scanning the 3 paragraphs I've found**
>
> **Russian and Ukrainian prisoners of war have been repeatedly abused and exposed to public curiosity,[28][29] and on at least two occasions Russian prisoners have been tortured[30][31] and killed.[32]**
>
> Besides the above quote and the section 'Treatment of prisoners of war' - subsection 'Russian prisoners of war' (which is probably what the above quote was summarising), is that it for Ukrainian war crimes (committed during the 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine) ?

**In fact, even now, I struggle to see any content that is not from that wikipedia page despite your claim that you fixed the issue.**

You're listed as a new contributor.  But that's not entirely true.  You have 7 years seniority on Scifi for example, with sizable score.  You shouldn't be surprised stack exchange communities have certain expectations about how to ask questions.  And reasons for closing questions that do not meet those criteria.

I'll vote to reopen if the question can be refocussed correctly on the main subject:  whether or not Ukraine has committed any war crimes.

Keep in mind however that this is a sensitive subject, which is seeing a lot of disinformation being thrown around.  For example, Russian accusations of genocide by Ukraine in Donbas.  Closures on this type of topic is frequent - be especially mindful of your phrasing and the credibility of the sources you quote.

And even a well asked question may not be fully answerable at this point in time.

p.s. Wikipedia can be problematic on ongoing controversial current event subjects.  For example, [Wahhabism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahhabism) was long a competing cesspit of partisan edits.  It's somewhat settled down now but asking any question based on its contents a few years back would have been counterproductive.

Comment: Part1. https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/can-you-reopen-the-question-what-war-crimes-has-ukraine-committed-during-the-20

Part2. https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6309/question-was-reopened-and-then-edited-to-be-shorter-and-then-closed-again

Comment: In re "I'll vote to reopen if the question can be refocussed correctly on the main subject: whether or not Ukraine has committed any war crimes." I would actually vote close a Q like that. Same goes if you substitute Russia for Ukraine. For the reasons I explained under that Q, briefly... as phrased it implies at least leadership responsibility or possibly even "collective guilt". The vast majority of the war crimes of the kind alleged in this war (and wiki article), i.e. those by bombardment are hard to prove to UN court standards...

Comment: see https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74028/are-there-examples-of-convictions-for-war-crimes-committed-with-artillery-or-air (And yeah, I'm aware of Bucha and so forth, the Russian soldier already convicted in Ukraine for shooting a civilian etc.)

Comment: @Fizz No, war crimes emphatically does **not** require command control orders.  Just listened to legalese podcast re. exactly that.  The point in 1949 was to make *individuals* liable for war crimes (thus dissuading them), not just hold their state accountable.  A US sergeant goes berserk and kills Afghans?:  war crime.  Orders ordering war crimes?  Yes, that's another aspect, but it is not a precondition.

Comment: [War Crime and Punishment - Horns of a Dilemma (podcast) | Listen Notes](https://www.listennotes.com/podcasts/horns-of-a-dilemma/war-crime-and-punishment-ZsSrjHoDfuq/)

Comment: Yes, but it's not the US as a whole held responsible in that case. By the way, lack of "in house" investigations / prosecutions *does* open the command hierarchy to charges of war crimes themselves, under the doctrine of [command responsibility](https://lieber.westpoint.edu/hays-parks-doctrine-command-responsibility/). It's worth nothing that in some ICTY cases simply dismissing the sub-commander of a unit (not necessarily charging or investigating him) was held as casting sufficient doubt as to the whether the higher level could be held responsible (Blaškić case IIRC).

Comment: @Fizz OK, since we are both aware of the distinction, I'll take "has Ukraine committed any war crimes" as shorthand for "have any Ukrainian forces committed war crimes" rather than "has the Ukrainian government ordered its forces to commit war crimes".  That seems like a fair question to be asking.  What exactly the OP meant however is not all that clear since they got all stuck on asking about wikipedia's article.

Answer (score 2):

The question was closed because:

> This question does not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes within the scope defined in the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Please have a look at that and see if you can rephrase your question to meet the requirements. As this is a very sensitive question, but potentially an interesting one, you will need to be very careful about how you phrase the question.

Comment: Part1. https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/can-you-reopen-the-question-what-war-crimes-has-ukraine-committed-during-the-20

Part2. https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6309/question-was-reopened-and-then-edited-to-be-shorter-and-then-closed-again