# Question was reopened and then edited to be shorter and then closed again?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions, closed-questions

Part1. [Can you reopen the question "What war crimes has Ukraine committed during the 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine?"](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/can-you-reopen-the-question-what-war-crimes-has-ukraine-committed-during-the-20)

Part2. [Question was reopened and then edited to be shorter and then closed again?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6309/question-was-reopened-and-then-edited-to-be-shorter-and-then-closed-again)

---

See here:

[What type and scale of war crimes has Ukraine committed during the 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/73883/what-type-and-scale-of-war-crimes-has-ukraine-committed-during-the-2022-russian)

1. Post Reopened by convert, BCLC, SurpriseDog, Alexei, Ekadh Singh - Reinstate Monica
   occurred Jun 28 at 21:32
2. shortened to focus on the question by Trilarion
3. Post Closed as "Not suitable for this site" by Carduus, eps, Timur Shtatland, Mort, Burt_Harris

So I guess Trilarion was wrong to shorten?

Comment: I don't think the edit caused it to be closed again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to make the question on topic and also respect the original idea behind the question as much as possible at the same time and I think that it is on topic. Unfortunately others think differently. I voted to reopen, but that's all I can do.

The StackExchange system achieves consensus by basically exhausting the close/reopen votes everyone has on each question. This means that one could interpret more people wanting to close it than to reopen it as those wanting to have it open as "being wrong" although I wouldn't go so far.

If you think my edit did not improve the question, roll back to a previous version and see if the question maybe gets reopened faster.